# I'm having error related to localhost. I'm trying to implement multi-threaded server client chat server

Tags: java, localhost

Here is the code I'm trying to make work but I'm getting this IOException about localhost not available.

```
public class MultiThreadChatClient implements Runnable{

    // Declaration section
    // clientClient: the client socket
    // os: the output stream
    // is: the input stream

    static Socket clientSocket = null;
    static PrintStream os = null;
    static DataInputStream is = null;
    static BufferedReader inputLine = null;
    static boolean closed = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // The default port 

    int port_number=5050;
        String host="localhost";


    // Initialization section:
    // Try to open a socket on a given host and port
    // Try to open input and output streams
    try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(host, port_number);
            inputLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host "+host);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host "+host);
        }

    // If everything has been initialized then we want to write some data
    // to the socket we have opened a connection to on port port_number 

        if (clientSocket != null && os != null && is != null) {
            try {

        // Create a thread to read from the server

                new Thread(new MultiThreadChatClient()).start();

        while (!closed) {
                    os.println(inputLine.readLine()); 
                }

        // Clean up:
        // close the output stream
        // close the input stream
        // close the socket

        os.close();
        is.close();
        clientSocket.close();   
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
            }
        }
    }           

    public void run() {     
    String responseLine;

    // Keep on reading from the socket till we receive the "Bye" from the server,
    // once we received that then we want to break.
    try{ 
        while ((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(responseLine);
        if (responseLine.indexOf("*** Bye") != -1) break;
        }
            closed=true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
    }
    }
}
```

Exception I'm getting is :

> Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host localhost

Comment: what line throws the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error might be due to there is no server listening to the connection request. **Start the server program first and then start the client**. 
*Else try this also*: Socket constructor needs first parameter as `InetAddress` instead of `String`
You have to use getByName(String) method for initializing the host to socket object.
modify your socket constructor as follows:

```
clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(host), port_number);
```

Comment: @elyashiv socket constructor throws the exception

Comment: @SagarPatwardhan Have you tried the above solution of changing the constructor parameter from String to InetAddress?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you enabled TCP on port 5050.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `localhost`, give your local ip address.
To know the local ip address go to the command prompt and type `ipconfig`.

**Example**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // The default port.
    int portNumber = 6679;
    // The default host.
    String host = "192.150.46.2";
```